# Not able to redirect to login page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using membership provide and not able to redirect to login page but after refresh page it goes to login..

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session["UserName"] == null)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            Session.Clear();
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login");
            //filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Account/Login");
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login", true);

Comment: @NarekArzumanyan no luck :(